# How to validate the json in multiple ways, AJV Json?

Tags: json, ajv

I am currently trying to validate the structure of a Json that meets certain requirements using the AJV Json library. The JSON structure scenarios will be like this:
1 Scenario (Valid, correct, must pass)

```
{
"QuoteDocuments": {
"CLQuoteXML": {
"QuoteObject": {}
}
}
}
```

2.Scenario (Valid, must pass):

```
{
  "QuoteDocuments": {
   "CLQuoteDocument": {
    "CLQuoteObject": {}
   }
  }
}
```

3 Scenario (Invalid, not correct):

```
{
"QuoteDocuments": {
"NOTEXIST": {
"NOTHING": {}
}
}
}
```

4.Scenario (invalid, not correct):

```
{
"QuoteDocuments": {
"CLQuoteDocument": {
"CLQuoteObject": {}
},
"CLQuoteXML": {
"QuoteObject": {}
}
}
}
```

5. Scenario (Invalid, not correct):

   {
   "QuoteDocuments": {
   "CLQuoteDocument": {
   "CLQuoteObject": "String"
   },
   }
   }

However, I have the schema rules in this way:

```
{
      "QuoteDocuments": {
        "$id": "quoteDocumentsId",
        "type": "object",
        "errorMessage": {
          "type": "The ${0#} property must be an object"
        },
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "CLQuoteXML": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["QuoteObject"]
              }
            },
            "required": ["CLQuoteXML"]
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "CLQuoteDocument": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["CLQuoteObject"]
              }
            },
            "required": ["CLQuoteDocument"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

but it is not working for me since the json has this structure:

```
{
"QuoteDocuments": {
"CLQuoteDocument": {
"QuoteObject": ""
}
}
}
```

Indicates these validation errors:
must have required property 'CLQuoteXML'
must have required property 'CLQuoteObject'
must match exactly one schema in oneOf

Which makes no sense since in the case that the CLQuoteDocument property is already present, it no longer has to indicate that 'CLQuoteXML' is required, in that case it would only have to indicate that CLQuoteObject is required since it is the continuing property.

It means that if the json carries the property
CLQuoteXML should no longer indicate that the CLQuoteDocument property is required, and if the json already has the CLQuoteDocument property it should no longer indicate that CLQuoteXML is required.

Then the workflow would be that if the CLQuoteXML property exists it should continue the validation rules only those found under 'CLQuoteXML' as would be required to request QuoteObject.

But if only the CLQuoteDocument property goes and not the CLQuoteXML then the workflow goes down or to the instructions under CLQuoteDocument which would request the CLQuoteObject field as required.

Since sometimes the json will have this structure:

```
{
"QuoteDocuments": {
"CLQuoteDocument": {
"CLQuoteObject": {}
}
}
}
```

either

```
{
"QuoteDocuments": {
"CLQuoteXML": {
"QuoteObject": {}
}
}
}
```

If the json structure is different, change the properties to that one then it should give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using JSON Schema and not some other variation of json validation.

You haven't given any constraints on what the `QuoteObject` must be.

Give this a try and see if it works. You didn't clearly state the actual requirements are for the validation to succeed.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "QuoteDocuments": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "required": [
                        "CLQuoteXML"
                    ],
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "CLQuoteXML": {
                            "required": [
                                "QuoteObject"
                            ],
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "QuoteObject": {
                                    "$ref": "#/$defs/QuoteObject"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "CLQuoteDocument"
                    ],
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "CLQuoteDocument": {
                            "required": [
                                "QuoteObject"
                            ],
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "QuoteObject": {
                                    "$ref": "#/$defs/QuoteObject"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "QuoteObject": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {}
        }
    }
}
```